# SQL query through an intermediate table

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, relational-division

Given the following tables:

```
Recipes
| id | name
| 1  | 'chocolate cream pie'
| 2  | 'banana cream pie'
| 3  | 'chocolate banana surprise'

Ingredients
| id | name
| 1  | 'banana'
| 2  | 'cream'
| 3  | 'chocolate'

RecipeIngredients
| recipe_id | ingredient_id
|     1     |      2
|     1     |      3
|     2     |      1
|     2     |      2
|     3     |      1
|     3     |      3
```

How do I construct a SQL query to find recipes where ingredients.name = 'chocolate' and ingredients.name = 'cream'?

Comment: fyi... The recipeIngredients is called a MappingTable...

Comment: @Garis Suero: There's *lots* of synonyms - xref, lookup, mapping, link - there's defined standard name for a table that provide a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called relational division. A variety of techniques are discussed [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

One alternative not yet given is the double NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM Recipes r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Ingredients i
                  WHERE name IN ('chocolate', 'cream')
                  AND NOT EXISTS
                      (SELECT * FROM RecipeIngredients ri
                       WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.id
                       AND ri.ingredient_id = i.id))
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for the reference and an answer that works!

There is a minor error in the last line, should be "AND ri.ingredient_id = i.id))"

Comment: @Bryan, Cheers. I've fixed it on my answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
  SELECT r.name
    FROM RECIPES r
    JOIN RECIPEINGREDIENTS ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.id
    JOIN INGREDIENTS i ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
                      AND i.name IN ('chocolate', 'cream')
GROUP BY r.name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2
```

The key point here is that the count must equal the number of ingredient names.  If it's not a distinct count, there's a risk of false positives due to duplicates.

Comment: The first option looks like what I want.  I tried it with no joy using PostgreSQL 8.3.5 and SQLite3.  

I tried with just one ingredient and for each of the tree ingredients, in turn, I get 2 rows back as I would expect.  

But, when I try with 2 ingredients, I get 0 rows.

Comment: That's what you get for not specifying the databases are you testing against.  The S in SQL doesn't mean "Standardized"; beyond a basic SELECT there's almost no chance of being 100% portable to all vendors.

Comment: Which database would this work with?  Maybe I can compare syntax and see how to apply it to PostgreSQL.  Your style of solution is easier for me to understand than the NOT EXISTS

Comment: @Bryan - RE: Easier to understand. The double negative does take a bit of getting used to. To reformulate it in English it is saying `Select those recipes where there isn't an ingredient in the list (chocolate, cream) that isn't in the recipe.`

Comment: @OMG That query doesn't look quite right as is to me. It seems to be saying that for each row ri.ingredient_id will have 2 different values.

Comment: @OMG but you are doing two mutually exclusive inner joins from it's ingredient_id. See here for SQL Server results http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/3092

Comment: @Martin Smith: You're right, I confirmed on SQL Server 2008 Express - it's because of the inner join.

Answer (score 4):

If you're searching for multiple associations then the simplest way to write the query is to use multiple `EXISTS` conditions instead of a single straight `JOIN`.

```
SELECT r.id, r.name
FROM Recipes r
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM RecipeIngredients ri
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i
        ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
    WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.id
    AND i.name = 'chocolate'
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM RecipeIngredients ri
    INNER JOIN Ingredients i
        ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
    WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.id
    AND i.name = 'cream'
)
```

If you know for sure that the associations are unique (i.e. a single recipe can only have a single instance of each ingredient), then you can cheat a bit using a grouping subquery with a `COUNT` function and possibly speed it up (performance will depend on the DBMS):

```
SELECT r.id, r.Name
FROM Recipes r
INNER JOIN RecipeIngredients ri
    ON ri.recipe_id = r.id
INNER JOIN Ingredients i
    ON i.id = ri.ingredient_id
WHERE i.name IN ('chocolate', 'cream')
GROUP BY r.id, r.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Or, if a recipe might have multiple instances of the same ingredient (no `UNIQUE` constraint on the `RecipeIngredients` association table), you can replace the last line with:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: This caveat was mentioned in the second paragraph.  But I suppose it wouldn't hurt to add the alternative (it will run slower).

Answer (score 2):

```
select r.*
from Recipes r
inner join (
    select ri.recipe_id
    from RecipeIngredients ri 
    inner join Ingredients i on ri.ingredient_id = i.id
    where i.name in ('chocolate', 'cream')
    group by ri.recipe_id
    having count(distinct ri.ingredient_id) = 2
) rm on r.id = rm.recipe_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.name
FROM Recipes r
INNER JOIN RecipeIngredients ri ON
    ri.recipe_id = r.id
INNER JOIN Ingredients i ON
    i.id = ri.ingredient_id
WHERE
    i.name IN ( 'cream', 'chocolate' )
```

Edited following comment, thanks! This is the right way then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.name
FROM Recipes r
INNER JOIN RecipeIngredients ri ON
    ri.recipe_id = r.id
INNER JOIN Ingredients i ON
    i.id = ri.ingredient_id AND
    i.name = 'cream'
INNER JOIN Ingredients i2 ON
    i2.id = ri.ingredient_id AND
    i2.name = 'chocolate'
```

Comment: This will also return recipes where cream is used without chocolate or chocolate is used without cream.

Answer (score 1):

a different way:

**Version 2 (as stored procedure) revised**

```
select   r.name
from   recipes r
where   r.id  = (select  t1.recipe_id
        from  RecipeIngredients t1 inner join
     RecipeIngredients     t2 on t1.recipe_id = t2.recipe_id
     and     t1.ingredient_id = @recipeId1
     and     t2.ingredient_id = @recipeId2)
```

**Edit 2:
[before people start screaming] :)**

This can be placed at the top of version 2, which will allow to query by name instead of passing in the id.

```
select @recipeId1 = recipe_id from Ingredients where name = @Ingredient1
select @recipeId2 = recipe_id from Ingredients where name = @Ingredient2
```

I've tested version 2, and it works. Most users where linking on the Ingredient table, in this case was totally not needed!

**Edit 3: (test results);**

When this stored procedure is run these are the results.

The results are of the format (First Recipe_id ; Second Recipe_id, Result)

```
1,1, Failed
1,2, 'banana cream pie'
1,3, 'chocolate banana surprise'
2,1, 'banana cream pie'
2,2, Failed
2,3, 'chocolate cream pie'
3,1, 'chocolate banana surprise'
3,2, 'chocolate cream pie'
3,3, Failed
```

Clearly this query does not handle case when both constraints are the same, but works for all other cases.

**Edit 4:(handling same constraint case):**

replacing this line:

```
r.id = (select t1...
```

to

```
r.id in (select t1...
```

works with the failed cases to give:

```
1,1, 'banana cream pie' and 'chocolate banana surprise'
2,2, 'chocolate cream pie' and 'banana cream pie'
3,3, 'chocolate cream pie' and 'chocolate banana surprise'
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that only one recipe_id can match and there is nothing limiting it to chocolate and cream

Comment: Try out version 2 (based on the same idea as first version). I've test it and it does work correctly.

Comment: You're still using ` r.id  =` assuming only one result. Ingredients is needed of course if you are matching up by ingredient name but I guess likely this will come from a list and the Ids will be known.

Comment: Just edited it again, because I knew people would start screaming!! :)

Comment: @Darknight Have you tested this with RecipeIngredients containing 2 different recipes both containing chocolate and cream?