# How to write IF ELSE statements in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have tables `posts` and `users`

basically i want to query if the column `privacy` of `posts` table is `0` it means post is `public` and i want to show this to everyone. but if `privacy` column is `1,2,3,4` it means this post is only for users with ID `1, 2, 3 and 4`

Comment: And what should be the outcome of your query?

Comment: Do you want to say, you've got comma separated values in your privacy column? That would almost never be a good idea.

Comment: can you post sqlfiddle with your database schema and some sample data?

Comment: yes its comma separated value, what way do you prefer? i m not that good at SQL actually..

Comment: @user2765602 I would use a junction table with three columns: `user_id`, `post_id` and `privacy` or so.

Comment: i want the query outcome, posts for person whos id is in PRIVACY column OR privacy column be 0(public) so the person sees it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a conditional problem it's a *sql join through table* association problem.

You need to create a join table that associates a post to a user. You can then use a join to select posts based upon their assignment to a user.

The SQL might look something like this

To select posts assigned to user ID = 4

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` 
    LEFT JOIN `posts_users` ON (`posts`.`id` = `posts_users`.`post_id`) 
    WHERE `posts_users`.`user_id` = 4;
```

You have also made the assumption that if a post has no users assigned to it, then it's a public post. That requires a check for NULL associations.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` 
    LEFT JOIN `posts_users` ON (`posts`.`id` = `posts_users`.`post_id`) 
    WHERE `posts_users`.`user_id` IS NULL;
```

If you want to find both public and associated posts, then you use a logical OR to match both rules.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` 
    LEFT JOIN `posts_users` ON (`posts`.`id` = `posts_users`.`post_id`) 
    WHERE `posts_users`.`user_id` = 4
       OR `posts_users`.`user_id` IS NULL;
```

Comment: i want the query outcome, posts for person whos id is in PRIVACY column OR privacy column be 0(public) so the person sees it.

Comment: `posts_users` is a third data table that defines `post_id` and `user_id` columns. For each user that owns a post there needs to be a record to define that association.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029454/sql-query-through-an-intermediate-table