# mapping of areas with multiple users

Tags: sql, join, database-design, relational-database

I have areas like sector 1, sector 1 a, sector 1 b, sector 1 c and multiple cable operators who are working in either full sector(i.e sector 1) or any of the sub sectors. I have created table of cable operators and want to map them with areas. If I set up area table like  sector 1, sector 1 a, sector 1 b, sector 1 c each with their own Primary Key then how can I reference these sectors in single row of cable operators provided that we have to get the cable operators working in that particular sector.

My table structures are as follows:

Operators

```
| id | name
| 1  | 'abc'
| 2  | 'def'
| 3  | 'ghi'
```

areas

```
| id | name
| 1  | 'sector 1'
| 2  | 'sector 1a'
| 3  | 'sector 1b'
| 4  | 'sector 1c'
| 5  | 'sector 1d'
| 6  | 'sector 2'
| 7  | 'sector 2a'
| 8  | 'sector 2b'
| 9  | 'sector 2c'
| 10  | 'sector 2d'
```

I have `operatorsareas` table where I have map operators with areas as follows:
operatorsareas

```
| op_id | area_id
| 1     | 1
| 2     | 1
| 3     | 1
| 1     | 7
| 2     | 8
| 3     | 7
```

Now I have used this query which gives me no result:

```
select o.id, o.name from operator as o
where not exists(select * from areas a where id in (1,7,8) and not exists(select * from operatorareas as oa where oa.operatorid=o.id 
and oa.areaid = a.id))
```

I have taken the reference of following link:

[SQL query through an intermediate table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029454/sql-query-through-an-intermediate-table)

I need a guidance regarding structuring of the tables.

Comment: 1) Do you mean to have more than one Operator in an Area (Sector or SubSector) ? 2) I don't see why the linked SQL is relevant. What result set do you want from the query (in English) ?

Answer (score 2):

### Initial Problem

Your Sector/Subsector designation **breaks 1NF**:

- **Each domain** [column] **must be Atomic wrt to the** [datatypes available in the] **platform.**

That is a gross Normalisation error, which will have horrendous consequences downstream.  The correction is:

- Sector is one datum, one column, eg. `Sector 1`
- SubSector is a separate datum, a separate column, eg. `a`, `b`, `c`

### The Data • What is it ?

> I need a guidance regarding structuring of the tables.

Ok.  But what the data actually means, is not at all clear.

From the little info you have given, the following **Predicates** can be derived:

- Each Operator is assigned to 0-or-1 Area 

  <sup>Assumption: an Operator cannot be in more than one place at a time

  Assumption: an Operator may not be assigned</sup>
- Each [assigned] Area is one of { Sector | SubSector | Unassigned }
  AreaType is the Discriminator
- Each Sector comprises 0-to-n SubSectors
  Each Sector is occupied by 0-to-n Operators
- Each SubSector is occupied by 0-to-n Operators

Please check and ensure that each is true (otherwise the data model is garbage).

### Relational Data Model

Assuming those Predicates are correct, the Normalised Relational data model is:

[image: Amit2TA]

#### Subtype • Exclusive

> operators are working in **either** full sector **or** any of the sub sectors

- What you are seeking in Logic terms is an **OR Gate**, in Relational terms, it is an **Exclusive Subtype**

  - Refer to **[Subtype](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf)** for full details on Subtype implementation.

#### Note • Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners or novices, wrt a Relational database.

### The Query • What is it ?

> Now I have used this query which gives me no result

We do not know what result set you are attempting to obtain.

- At this point, it does not appear to be related to the linked Question & Answer.
- Please explain what result set you would like to obtain, in English.  Hopefully observing the given data model.
- Supplying the required SQL would then a simple matter.

Enjoy.  Please feel free to ask specific questions.